# Own C library with memory-related issues

Tags: c

I am writing a C library for strings management, it would be like python interface as much as possible, but I have the following question:

Should my library allocate memory, or the client has to do it?

for example, see my `center` method:

```
char * center(char * str, int width, char fillchar)
```

The issue with this approach is that the client has to free every time this method is called.

See more here:

https://github.com/jiss2891/pystrings

Comment: You can design it either way (client allocation or library allocation) — there will be consequences on the interface with either decision.  It will be easier to use if the library manages the memory — as long as you provide the helper functions necessary to allow the users to release the memory when their code is done with a string.  Creating a garbage-collected string library is a vastly (two or three orders of magnitude) more complicated exercise — don't even think of it while you're asking this question.

Comment: Q: Given that C isn't a garbage-collected language ... how would the storage get freed if the client didn't do it?  In other words, you can (and probably should) put some kind of "free" API in your library ... but wouldn'the client still have to call it?  How would the library "know" when to free the storage otherwise?

Comment: You could write code that uses the [Boehm GC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector)... but...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala do you mean that it is difficult or its not good enough?

Comment: @JuanIgnacioSánchez well, the Boehm GC does have its limitations. I've not used it personally and frankly I think no one should use GC with C before they can write code that does not need GC :D

Comment: I would vote for the library to allocate the memory. Then the client is only responsible for freeing the memory. If the client provides the memory: A) the client needs to know how to calculate the correct amount of memory, B) if the client miscalculates, and allocates insufficient space, the result is a buffer overrun, and C) if the client uses dynamic memory allocation, then it has to free the memory anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of times when I'm writing such functions, they're for formatting purposes, whereby the centered or otherwise-prettyfied string won't be needed for long. When that's a safe assumption, I typically declare a static wraparound buffer in the function, something like the following...

```
char *center_or_whatever ( char *instring, int some_param /*,etc*/ ) {
  /* --- wrap-around buffer --- */
  #define NBUFFS 999
  #define BUFFWIDTH 999
  static char buffer[NBUFFS][BUFFWIDTH];
  static int  ibuff = 999999;
  char *outstring = NULL;
  /* --- assign next buffer to outstring --- */
  if ( ++ibuff >= NBUFFS ) ibuff=0;
  outstring = buffer[ibuff];
  /* --- check to make sure instring and other params won't make
     outstring exceed BUFFWIDTH, truncate (or whatever) if necessary, etc --- */
  /* --- now do whatever your function's supposed to do --- */
  strcpy(outstring,instring); /* just for example */
  return ( outstring );
  } /* --- end-of-center_or_whatever() --- */
```

...So now, nobody has to malloc or free anything, so long as the user won't be needing the output for more than NBUFFS calls to the function, and as long as the output won't ever need to exceed BUFFWIDTH chars. Those arguably aren't safe assumptions, but I frequently find something like NBUFFS=64 and BUFFWIDTH=128 are more than safe enough for the purposes of whatever I'm programming at the time. And the static allocation of [64][128] bytes is pretty much unnoticeable. So, most of the time for me, the ease and safety of not worrying about malloc/free is well worth the extra few bytes and extra few lines of code.

Note that you can also declare one big, long **static char buffer[99999];** and maintain a pointer that's initialized **static char *buffptr=buffer**. Then during each call, assign **outstring** to the current **buffptr**, bump **buffptr**, and wrap it around when it would overflow. That's a little more flexible, and takes a few (but not many) extra lines of code.

Comment: The single big buffer solution tends to waste less memory unless most of the strings are close to the maximum length for one string.  It also allows for a few odd-ball very long strings without truncating them unnecessarily.